Put text in front of responses using the enumext package
I'm using the enumext package to generate the answers to the objective questions at the end of the text. In addition to the answer, I would like to add a link to a video that contains the resolution of the question. Is it possible to do this? The figure below illustrates what I want.

\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}% Margens
\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end), 
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfigure}              
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}

\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{placement=center,angle=58,hshift=0,vshift=0,scale=8,contents={Prof. Ulisses Moreira},color=black,opacity=0.07}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Prof. Ulisses Moreira}
\rhead{Gás ideal}
\cfoot{ - \thepage\hspace{1pt} -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{%
        \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip2pt%
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip-\headrulewidth\vskip-4pt
}}
\makeatother % linha dupla

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{2.2cm}}

\begin{document}    

\begin{enumext}[list-indent=0pt,save-ans=test,show-ans=false]   
\item O que é um gás? % letra e

\begin{keyans}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item Gás é um fluido que não possui as propriedades de compressibilidade e expansibilidade, portanto ocupa somente uma porção do volume em que está contido.
    \item Gás é um líquido cujas moléculas que o constituem estão bastante espaçadas umas das outras.
    \item Gás é um fluido que apresenta somente a propriedade de expansibilidade.
    \item Gás é um fluido que sofre ação da gravidade e não possui propriedades de compressibilidade.
    \item*[\url{https://www.youtube.com/}] Gás é um fluido que possui as propriedades de compressibilidade e expansibilidade e que tende a ocupar todo o espaço onde está contido. %correta
\end{keyans}
    

\end{enumext}

\end{document}


It is a multiple choice question?...If ​​so, that is, you are using the keyans or keyans* environments, you can try using \item*[your url] ...

I'm using keyans. Initially I tried:
\item*[\url{link}] and it didn't compile. After that I tried without the \url, like \item*[link]. This way it compiled but in the response it does not appear as a link. Is there any other way?

could you add a minimal working example people can compile?

@PabloGonzálezL I put the code below the image, as you asked.

This:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}% Margens
\usepackage{indentfirst}                % Coloca parágrafo no início texto
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}          % Linguagem português
\usepackage{multicol}                   % Texto em duas colunas
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\newcommand{\fixspacing}{\vspace{0pt plus 1filll}\mbox{}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\gridwidth}
\newlength{\gridheight}
\newlength{\gridstep}
\newcommand{\gridfill}[1][]{%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid start) at (0,0); }%
    \vfill\hfill\null%
    \tikz[remember picture]{ \coordinate (grid end) at (0,0); }%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, #1]
        \pgfmathsetlength{\gridstep}{\tikz@grid@x}
        \draw let \p1 = (grid start |- grid end),
        \p2 = (grid start -| grid end),
        \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)},
        \n2 = {veclen(\x2,\y2)}
        in \pgfextra{
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridwidth}{int(\n1 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \pgfmathsetlength{\gridheight}{int(\n2 / \gridstep) * \gridstep}
            \draw[shift={(grid start)}] (0,0) grid (\gridwidth,-\gridheight);
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{xcolor}                     % Mudar cor das palavras
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % Inclusão de gráficos

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)

\usepackage{amsmath}                    % Ambiente Matemático
\usepackage{array}                      % Para colocar tabelas
\usepackage{float}                      % fixa a figura no lugar
\usepackage[a]{esvect}                  % vetor pra maiuscula
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide=0pt, align=left}

\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
\backgroundsetup{placement=center,angle=58,hshift=0,vshift=0,scale=8,contents={Prof. Ulisses Moreira},color=black,opacity=0.07}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amstext}
%%\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}
\usepackage{textcomp,mathcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{enumext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead{Prof. Ulisses Moreira}
\rhead{Gás ideal}
\cfoot{ - \thepage\hspace{1pt} -}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\makeatletter
\def\headrule{{%
        \if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip2pt%
        \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth\vskip-\headrulewidth\vskip-4pt
}}
\makeatother % linha dupla

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-2.5cm}
    \setlength{\footskip}{2.2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumext}[list-indent=0pt,save-ans=test,show-ans=false]
\item O que é um gás? % letra e

\begin{keyans}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item Gás é um fluido que não possui as propriedades de 
    compressibilidade e expansibilidade, portanto ocupa somente uma 
    porção do volume em que está contido.
    \item Gás é um líquido cujas moléculas que o constituem estão 
    bastante espaçadas umas das outras.
    \item Gás é um fluido que apresenta somente a propriedade de 
    expansibilidade.
    \item Gás é um fluido que sofre ação da gravidade e não possui 
    propriedades de compressibilidade.
    \item*[\noexpand\url{https://www.youtube.com/}] Gás é um fluido que 
    possui as propriedades de compressibilidade e expansibilidade e que 
    tende a ocupar todo o espaço onde está contido. %correta
\end{keyans}
\end{enumext}

\printkeyans[columns=1]{test}

\end{document}

The key here is to use \noexpand:
\item*[\noexpand\url{https://www.youtube.com/}]

Comment or remove \DeclareUrlCommand :
%\DeclareUrlCommand\url{\color{blue}}

Add urlcolor=blue:
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}



When I open the pdf and click on the link, I am not directed to the website.

Mmm....work ...delete your .aux, .out a run (two times)

I'm not sure why it works with Acrobat and not with Evince/Atril (I know it's an expansion problem), for now I'll leave you an updated answer that works in Evince/Atril

Now there is a correct solution, in the chat they explained to me what was happening behind, clearly there is a problem in the implementation so it is likely that this will work without using \noexpand in the next version.

Thanks again Pablo. It worked perfectly.
